# UI Notifications for both Mobile and Web

Tags: user-interface, push-notification, notifications, amazon-sns

I'm looking at adding realtime notifications into my website and mobile application and I'm struggling with deciding the most effective way to do so.  What I'm trying to do is shown below (example with Amazon SNS):

1. John Doe tries to notify Hugh Jackman with a message
2. My application will store the message in the database (sets value to "Not read yet")
3. My application will then send anotification to SNS with the notification id and user id
4. Hugh Jackman logs into my website - Javascript then consumes the SNS message (gotten by user id) and sends alert in the UI
5. Hugh Jackman reads it, then my application sets the message to "Has been Read" in the DB
6. Hugh Jackman logs into mobile app and since the message has already been consumed and has been read, there will be no alert.

**My questions:**

1. Is this a viable approach or is there a better one?  Would you change anything?
2. How should my UI contact the SNS service from the Web application?  I'm imaging though some JavaScript call with long polling, is this correct? Are there any examples?
3. Are there any better ways/technologies to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "SignalR came to mind but since I'm wanting mobile as well I crossed it off the list." Why do you cross signalr for mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with SignalR with SQL Dependency.  SNS with SQS should not be used as a database in regards to notifications.